# Calabash. Cómo obtener un elemento de una lista de items de una query, usando sólo la instrucción query

Tags: android, ios, ruby

Quiero hacer una query para obtener un sólo elemento. Ya sé cómo hacerlo a través del índice si la respuesta de la query es un array de varios elementos:

```
button = query("webView css:'button'")[position]
touch button
```

La respuesta de esta query es un array con varios elementos.

Pero estoy usando un patrón descrita en este enlace: https://blinkboxbooks.github.io/2015/01/21/oo-page-models-for-calabash.html

y lo que quiero es obtener el elemento a través sólo de una query específica, para luego poder generar el Element (que puedes ver en el link) y usar sus métodos asociados, como element.exists? o element.set_checked

La query concreta con la que me encuentro este problema es la siguiente:

**query("webView css:'name_class'")**

```
[
    [0] {
    "class" => "name_class",
    "nodeType" => "ELEMENT_NODE",
    "id" => "",
    "textContent" => "",
    "rect" => {
        "y" => 856,
        "x" => 44,
        "center_x" => 92,
        "height" => 96,
        "width" => 96,
        "top" => 189,
        "left" => 11,
        "center_y" => 904
    },
    "nodeName" => "DIV",
    "webView" => nil
},
    [1] {
    "class" => "name_class",
    "nodeType" => "ELEMENT_NODE",
    "id" => "",
    "textContent" => "",
    "rect" => {
        "y" => 1040,
        "x" => 164,
        "center_x" => 212,
        "height" => 96,
        "width" => 96,
        "top" => 235,
        "left" => 41,
        "center_y" => 1088
    },
    "nodeName" => "DIV",
    "webView" => nil
}
]
```

Esta respuesta me la da en los dispositivos iOS. En Android no tengo problema porque me da un campo "index" que puedo usar, pero en iOS no.

Como podéis ver no hay posibilidad de diferenciarlas salvo por el orden en el que aparecen. Si tuviera algún texto concreto o algún identificador podría identificar el elemento unívocamente con una query. En cualquier caso podría hacer el touch de la forma clásica:

```
checkbox = query("webView css:'name_class'")[1]
touch checkbox
```

Pero quiero usar la clase Element para hacer algo así:

```
checkbox = new Element("webView css:'name_class' {index LIKE 1}")
checkbox.touch
```

La parte de "{index LIKE 1}" me la he inventado, y es lo que necesito averiguar.
Resumiendo, necesito una forma de obtener un elemento situado en un array usando sólamente una query, sin hacer uso del índice del array.

Espero haberme explicado, porque es un tema un poco lioso.

Gracias por adelantado por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder al un elemento concreto de una lista puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma con query:

```
query("webView css:'name_class' index:1")
```

o con la sintaxis de Element que indicas

```
new Element("webView css:'name_class' index:1")
```

Comment: Puedes ver la documentación aquí -> https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/05-Query-Syntax#filtering

Comment: Muchas gracias. Acabo de verificar en Android y funciona correctamente. En cuanto pueda probarlo en iOS lo escribo aquí.

Comment: Ya está probado en dispositivo iOS y todo correcto. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si la respuesta ha solucionado la consulta, deberías marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo